# How to persist data in react even browser refreshed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Functions such as add and remove from cart works fine. But the data is not saved successfully after the browser is refreshed. How to keep the data in the cart even when the browser is refreshed.

here is my code. if there is any code you would like to see let me know

```
  import React, { useEffect } from "react";
  import { useStateValue } from "../hooks/StateProvider";

  function CheckoutPage() {
  const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basket));
  }, [basket]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const basketData = window.localStorage.getItem("basket");
    if (basketData !== null) dispatch(JSON.parse(basketData));
  }, []);
```

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

[image: here is the display on my browser console]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Web Api` for that . `sessionStorage` , `localStorage` , `Indexed DB` or etc..